# How can I get Gradle to add file deletion to the log output?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a Gradle script that contains several file deletion steps.  The files that are designated for deletion may or may not be present when the script is run, so simply adding `println` outputs isn't sufficient.  I tried working with `TaskActionListener()`, but it seems this class is only able to listen to when a task begins and finishes its actions, with no details of the actions actually being returned.

I noticed that Gradle's `Delete` task type contains a method called `getTargetFiles()`, which would seem to be what I'm looking for, however **I'm not using this task**--rather, I'm using the following syntax within other larger tasks:

`delete file("$projectDir/javadoc")`

The above is very convenient for what my project needs (I'm basically trying to convert a very large Ant build to Gradle and need to keep all the steps relatively the same rather than building it from the ground up, for the sake of... many other people involved).

It crossed my mind that I could just use the built-in AntBuilder (seeing as how Ant normally outputs what it's deleting) like so:

`ant.delete(dir: "$projectDir/javadoc")`

But it seems that Gradle kills the output on this as well!  I'd be happy to just run the script with the `-i` option for INFO level logging, but even this isn't enough to convince Gradle to log deletion messages.  Only `-d` will do the trick, but then of course I'm blasted with information overload.

Anyone have any ideas?  I've searched for days but haven't found a single thing to help.

Comment: Why not just add a `println` before the call to `delete`?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser: Using `println` would only print the intended includes, not the files that are actually getting deleted.  If I tell the script to delete a file that isn't there, I don't want the log to claim that it's getting deleted.  Also, I would eventually like to extend whatever solution I find for this to other file actions such as mkdir and copy.  Using `println` for all of these things would add a huge amount of extra lines to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write your own methods. For example:

```
def delete(Object... paths) {
    for (file in project.files(paths)) {
        if (file.exists()) {
            println "Deleting $file"
        }
    }
    project.delete(paths)
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, that's what I settled on already.  I was hoping there was some kind of listener I could use, but this gets the job done.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: There are a number of different listeners (e.g. see `Gradle#addListener`), but none for plain method calls.